# SyntaxError: invalid syntax for listen() in python socket programming

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, tcp, server

The following is the code to transfer file from Server. I am getting and error saying

**Error**
    s.listen(2)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

**Server code**

```
import socket
import threading
import os

def RetrFile(name,sock):
    filename = sock.recv(1024)
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        sock.send("EXISTS " + str(os.path.getsize(filename)))
        userResponse = sock.recv(1024)
        if userResponse[:2] == 'OK':
            with open(filename,'rb') as f:
                bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
                sock.send(bytesToSend)
                while bytesToSend != "":
                    bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
                    sock.send(bytesToSend)
    else:
        sock.send("ERR")
    sock.close()

def Main():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((socket.gethostname(),1235)
    s.listen(2)
    print("Server started")

    while True:
        c,addr = s.accept()
        print("Client connected ip:<" + str(addr) + ">")
        t = threading.Thread(target = RetrFile, arfs=("retrThread", c))
        t.start()

    s.close()

if __name__ = '__main__':
    Main()
```

Can someone help me out to understand why am I getting this error? I am new to python and socket programming.

Comment: I believe this is because you've got an extra `(` in the `bind` call on the previous line. Remove that and I think the syntax error will go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is missing the closing parenthesis of the tuple:

```
s.bind((socket.gethostname(),1235)
```